# PHP MySQLi Parameterized Query not functioning

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am updating my current unprotected queries to parameterized ones to protect from SQL Injection.

I have spent a few hours trying to sort this however cant find the issue, any help much appreciated.

BEFORE (echo $row['storeID'];) works before

```
$storeName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['store']); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM stores WHERE storeName = '$storeName'";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
```

AFTER

```
$storeName = $_GET['store'];
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM stores WHERE storeName = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $storeName);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

This echo should work but using statements it does not

```
 echo $row['storeID'];
```

Comment: No need to `mysqli_real_escape_string`, prepare will take care of it.

Comment: @digijay I removed the mysqli_real_escape_string from the question, thanks - any ideas why this still wont work ?

Comment: Have a look at the examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php You have to iterate the results. Sorry that I didn't see it, I'm more the PDO guy ...

Comment: I have read though that, thanks anyway

Comment: I have put the before and after code to make the question clearer

Comment: I would suggest asking yourself why you're using mysqli; it's a very low-level library and is far from ideal for direct use. PDO makes things much easier and more intuitive, if you need to stick with built-in PHP functions. If you're updating this code already, I would strongly consider switching.

Comment: I'd suggest to add the while loop from the example to your question instead of the echo (since this will definitly not work). Maybe someone else comes up with a solution.

Comment: @digijay I didnt think a loop would be required since there will only be a single row output

Comment: @miken32 I dont know PDO but agree it would probs be better, please would you mind just showing me how to do this single one in PDO then i can learn from this for all the others i need to do

Comment: @digijay I think PDO would be a better way to move forward but i just dont know how to do PDO, please could you convert this one to PDO and i can learn for the rest, it would be really appreciated

Comment: @digijay Would this be the suggested secure way ? $statement = $db->prepare("select * from stores where storeName = :name");
$statement->execute(array(':name' => "ebay"));
$row = $statement->fetch();

Comment: I rolled back your last edit as it was making the question too broad. Questions should be as narrow as possible, and stick with a single question.

Comment: @miken32 I understand, but would you consider the PDO query i had at the bottom of the question safe only as its different from the example you provided

Comment: @bradders: Gotta love PDO :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`mysqli_stmt_fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) you'll see this description:

> Fetch results from a prepared statement into the bound variables

So if you want to go this route, you'll need to ue [`mysqli_stmt_bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) as well:

```
$storeName = $_GET['store'];
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM stores WHERE storeName = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $storeName);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col1, $col2, $col3,...);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    // do stuff with $col1, $col2, etc.
}
```

Now, with each iteration of the loop, the bound result variables are given the value from the result set.

---

However, I'd strongly suggest moving to PDO, which is far less verbose:

```
$storeName = $_GET['store'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM stores WHERE storeName = ?");
$stmt->execute([$storeName]);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// now you have a simple array with all your results
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // do stuff with $row
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer, i will move forward with PDO... I have put together a query to select a single row, i have put this at the bottom of my question, would you consider this safe.. secure since its slightly different to yours?

Comment: Using named parameters is a good approach if you have a bunch of them; it can make it easier to keep track of them. For a single parameter like this, I feel that it's not worth the extra verbosity in your code, but it certainly doesn't hurt anything. It's a matter of personal opinion whether you want to use named or unnamed parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a call to `mysqli_stmt_get_result` before fetching the row:

```
$storeName = $_GET['store'];
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM stores WHERE storeName = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $storeName);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['id'];
```

Comment: Note that this function requires the `mysqlnd` driver.